# Deploy Maven to s3 bucket from jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3

I am completely new to CI/CD implementation. I am trying to create a pipeline that will package and deploy my jar to s3 buckets.

Please Note:
In aws console the IAM user that I created has full access to s3 and the policy simulator worked well.
I have create my s3 profile in jenkins and the "test connection" works well.

The "Release to aws' stage is failing with the following. Can anyone guide me here please. Unable to see what I am missing.

```
Downloading from s3.artifacts.snapshot: s3://panda.bucket.net/snapshot/com/panda/panda-app/1.0- 
SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
[WARNING] s3://panda.bucket.net/snapshot - Connection refused
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata com.panda:panda-app:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to 
s3.artifacts.snapshot (s3://panda.bucket.net/snapshot): Could not connect to repository
[INFO] Logged off - panda.bucket.net
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

My Jenkins file:

```
pipeline {
agent any
tools {
    maven 'maven'
    jdk 'jdk1.8'
}
stages {
    stage('SCM') {
                steps {
                    git 'https://username:password@gitlab.com/my-repo/panda-app'
                }
     }
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            bat 'mvn clean compile'
        }
    }
    stage('Release to aws') {
        steps {
            bat 'mvn deploy'
        }
     }
   }}
```

My build and distribution configuration in pom:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <artifactrepo.url>panda.bucket.net</artifactrepo.url>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>com.allogy.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-s3-wagon</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>s3.artifacts.release</id>
        <url>s3://${artifactrepo.url}/release</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>s3.artifacts.snapshot</id>
        <url>s3://${artifactrepo.url}/snapshot</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Settings.xml

```
<settings>
<server>
  <id>s3.artifacts.release</id>
  <username>MY_ACCESS_KEY</username>
  <password>MY_SECRET</password>
  <filePermissions>AuthenticatedRead</filePermissions>
</server>
<server>
  <id>s3.artifacts.snapshot</id>
  <username>MY_ACCESS_KEY</username>
  <password>MY_SECRET</password>
  <filePermissions>AuthenticatedRead</filePermissions>
</server>
```

Comment: You probably need to supply AWS credentials for the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to implement the deployment to S3 within maven? It is simpler to do it on the Jenkins pipeline, if that's an option for your case.

You need to have [AWS steps plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-aws/).

```
pipeline {
agent any
tools {
    maven 'maven'
    jdk 'jdk1.8'
}
stages {
    stage('SCM') {
                steps {
                    git 'https://username:password@gitlab.com/my-repo/panda-app'
                }
     }
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            bat 'mvn clean compile' //maybe package goal to leave the artifact ready to be released
        }
    }
    stage('Release to aws') {
        steps {
            withAWS(region:'yourS3Region', credentials:'awscredentialsID'){
                s3Upload(bucket:"yourBucketName", workingDir:'target', includePathPattern:'**/*'); // pick your jar or whatever you need
            }
        }
     }
   }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.! it worked with jenkins pipeline.